# sql works on phpmyadmin but not on php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table names courses and institution.
Here is my query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
IF NOT EXISTS temp  AS (SELECT course_name, ins_name
         FROM courses 
         where course_name='ACCA') ;

select institution.ins_name, address, contact, website, 
email from institution join temp on institution.ins_name = temp.ins_name
```

And here is my php script:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db_connect.php');
$sql="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
IF NOT EXISTS temp  AS (SELECT course_name, ins_name
         FROM courses 
         where course_name='ACCA') ;

 select institution.ins_name, address, contact, website, email from institution join temp on institution.ins_name = temp.ins_name";

$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn)); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ins_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"

?>
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. The error i get is:

MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select institution.ins_name, address, contact, website, email from institution j' at line 6

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every query must be executed separately. `create` and `select` are two different queries so first you need to call `mysqli_query` for `create` and then `mysqli_query` for `select`

Comment: got it. had to query them separately. Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

From [Multiple Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php):

> MySQL optionally allows having multiple statements in one statement
>   string. Sending multiple statements at once reduces client-server
>   round trips but requires special handling.
>
> Multiple statements or multi queries must be executed with
>   `mysqli_multi_query()`. The individual statements of the statement
>   string are separated by semicolon. Then, all result sets returned by
>   the executed statements must be fetched.

Alternatively, just fire two queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need alias on each column :

```
 select institution.ins_name, institution.address, institution.contact, institution.website, institution.email from institution join temp on institution.ins_name = temp.ins_name";
```